# How can you remove the .html extension from a URL if you have the same file name and folder name on the same directory

Tags: .htaccess, url

Ok, so I've tried looking up this answer, and talked to ppl on discord, but it doesn't seem like there is an answer for this, so this is probably my last stop.

This is my file structure

```
> index.html
> x (FOLDER)
   > i_am_in_x.html
   > xD.html
> y (FOLDER)
   > not.html
   > yes.html
> somefile.html
> x.html
> y.html
> styles (FOLDER)
> images (FOLDER)
```

The goal is: to remove the ".html" extension at the end of the page.


Example:

**example.com/x** instead of example.com/x.html;

**example.com/y/not** instead of example.com/y/not.html**

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

I've used a a few different codes. The one I'm currently using: (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html
```

Comment: Kindly do add your htaccess file in your question which you are using now, thank you.

Comment: I used a few different once. I added the one that i'm using right now in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DirectorySlash off` in your htaccess file. This will allow you to rewrite a file with the same name as directory.
At the top of your `.htaccess` ( before existing rules) put the following line :

```
DirectorySlash off
```

This turns off the slash on a directory and makes it possible to perform URL Rewriting. There are some advantages and disadvantages of using this.

Advantages :

You can use `RewriteRule` to remove the extension so you can just type `/folder` instead of `/folder.html` .

Disadvantages :

By disabling `directorySlash` functionalities your directory structure may be visible to browsers if they  direct access your directory  by going to `/folder/` .

Reference https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash